# go struct JSON decode always empty return &{}

Tags: go

What I can be doing wrong in my handler?

```
type Patient struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}


func createHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    r.ParseForm()
    p := new(Patient)
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&p)

    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Print(p)
}
```

I always get from `curl -X POST $PATH -d '{"firstName": "Julian"}'`

```
2016/01/23 17:33:50 &{  }
```

### Edit

I've added `fmt.Println(r)` and got this

```
2016/01/23 18:33:22 &{POST /patients/ HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Accept:[*/*] Content-Type:[application/json] User-Agent:[curl/7.46.0]] 0x9b2820 0 [] false localhost:8081 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:35394 /patients/ <nil> <nil>}
```

after debug the previous line I realized it's a problem with the subrouter of gorilla toolkit

Comment: What happens when you add the content-type to your POST? `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` (Your handler is running on my machine, but I am using Powershells Invoke-RestMethod, so speculating if something is wrong with the curl command...)

Comment: I got it to work with curl on my windows machine with escaping characters like this `curl.exe -X POST http://localhost:8080 -d "{\"FirstName\":\"Test Value\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`Not sure what os you are on? (windows is weird...)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Since you're using the JSON lib convention, then your post form data should be `FirstName` and not `firstName`. If you really wanted to use `firstName`, you need to add this struct tag to the field: `json:"firstName"`.

Next, you don't need to put `&` in `&p` anymore because `new(Patient)` already returns a pointer. Just put `p`.

Although personally, I'd just do `p := Patient{}` just so I know it's not a pointer and use `&p` in the decoder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `r.ParseForm`. You can read here

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm

> For POST or PUT requests, it also parses the request body

So your request body will be empty after the call of `ParseForm` and you will receive an empty struct.